# generar de forma dinámica un árbol con bootstrap-treeview

Tags: array, bootstrap-3

me he encontrado con este framework de boostrar para hacer estructuras en árbol pero tengo mis dudas.
La primera es saber si los parámetros del array, deben llamarse "Text" y "nodes" como en el ejemplo que añado, imagino que el json deberá tener una estructura concreta. Lo que me gustaría saber es como  debe ser el json o array para que este treeview funcione correctamente.

```js
 
 tree();
 
 
  
 function tree(){ //Funcion que hace el arbol
 var test_tree = [
 {
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [
    {
        text: "Child 1",
  nodes: [
        {
            text: "Grandchild-1",
   nodes: [
    {
     text: "Grandchild 111",
    },
    {
    text: "Grandchild 2",
    }
   ]
          },
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "Child 2",
   state: 
  {
   expanded: true,
  },
    }
    ]
  },

 
];
  
  
 //$('#test_tree').treeview({data: test_tree});
 
 $('#test_tree').treeview({
   expanded: true,
  data: test_tree,  
  levels: 5,
  backColor: 'white',
  color: '#686a10',
  borderColor: 'transparent',
  showBorder:false,
  highlightSelected: false,
  
  
 });
 
 


 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id ="Historias" class=" col-md-12"> <!--- COntenedor principal-->
 <div class="row  clearfix">
  <strong><div id="test_tree">
   
  </div></strong>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efectivamente las propiedades `text` y `nodes` son propias de la librería por lo que su nombre no puede cambiarse; ahora en cuanto a la estructura del Json que debes pasar para que el treeview funcione es la siguiente:

```
[{
   text: 'Objeto Padre',
   nodes: [{
      text: 'Objeto hijo',
      nodes: [{
         text: 'Objeto nieto'
      }]
   }]
}]
```

Si llevamos esto a un ejemplo más sencillo y fácil de digerir sería así:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var data = [
  {
    text: "Equipos españoles",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Real Madrid",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Gareth Bale"
          },
          {
            text: "Marcelo"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Barcelona",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Lio Messi"
          },
          {
            text: "Arturo Vidal"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Equipos ingleses",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Chelsea",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Pedro"
          },
          {
            text: "Eden Hazard"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Manchester City",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Gabriel Jesús"
          },
          {
            text: "Ederson"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
];
  
  $('#tree').treeview({
    data: data
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div id="tree"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
```

Tienes toda la documentación **[acá](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview)**

Nos comentas si te sirve :)

Comment: Estimado Paulo, está buena tu respuesta. He leído la documentación que proporcionaste y no he podido instalar boosttrap-treeview, por lo que he intentado decargarla manualmente pero ni siquiera los ejemplos que trae dentro me funcionan ¿me podrías dar una mano?

Comment: Claro... contactame por Skype a mi correo (pauloc1989@hotmail.com) y te ayudaré!